# Property Sigma Algebra

Tags: measure-theory, real-analysis

Is the set { $ \cup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} C_{i} \times D_{i} : C_{i} \in \mathcal{L} \ , D_{i} \in \mathcal{B}^{n}  \ $ } a  sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{n}$ ?

Comment: Let $ X,Y \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ Borel sets. Is the set $ X \times Y \subset \mathbb{R}^{2n} $ a Borel set ? 

Comment: already answered here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/38795/borel-sets-on-rn

Comment: Valerio, are you saying the answer to the OP's question above is at your link? It seems to be a different question there, although the theme is related.

Answer (score 4):

Your collection is not closed under complement. To see this, observe that the diagonal $\Delta=\{(x,x)\mid x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is not in your collection, since the only rectangles it contains are singletons, but there are uncountably many. But the complement of $\Delta$ is the union of countably many open rectangles, so the complement of $\Delta$ is in your collection.

Comment: This is a good idea ... "diagonal" does not quite make sense for $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R^n$, though.

Comment: Yes, Gerald, I had in mind just the case $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$. But for the general case, one can use the same idea with $\Delta\times\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, which is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n$, whose complement is therefore in the OP's collection, but the set itself is not for similar reasons to what I say in my answer.